# ANGULAR - Resource URL changes when Reload Page

Tags: angular, browser, resources

I have a problem with loading resources when I reload the page after going on that Route in Angular.

When I go to that Route with the button, so with the angular routing, it works normally:
[Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiuBc.png)
[Sources loaded correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU4bY.png)

In the same page, if I try to press F5 (so reload the page), a blank window appear, and in the Console log i see:
[Sources loading error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGnQ3.png)

I think te problem is related to the URL of the source, because the browser is searching in the wrong place (inside the compoment folder :/ ) :
[Wrong source URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz9K6.png)
Instead the **correct ** URL is:
[Correct source URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anPAX.png)

So I receive the error messages:
[Console error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS9rO.png)

I don't know why it act whit this behaviour and how to fix it.
It happened for the first time when I added the query param to the route.
In app-routing.module.ts :
[Component Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsVIy.png)

Can someone help me please?

I tried to understand the problem, I wanted to refresh the page without block the system.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with your `base` element in the `head` of your `index.html`.

If your `href` is looking for resources relative to your current page, it may not be able to locate them (for example, if your `href` is set to `./`, it would try to look for resources under `localhost:4200/current-route` instead of `localhost:4200`).

You can find more information about it in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag).